# Background-Image should resolution of window

Tags: html, css

let's say my body-tag has a background-image with the resolution of 1920 x 1020. When I load my page, my window only has the size of ~800 x 800. I don't want to load the 1920 x 1020 resolution, only the 800 x 800 I'll need to display the backgroundimage.

Any way to achieve this?

http://jsfiddle.net/49qvq7rw/

```
<div class="give_me_background_plx">

</div>

body,
html {
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
}

.give_me_background_plx {
  background: url("http://placehold.it/1920x1000") center center, 100% 100%; 
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
}
```

Edit:
See the jsfiddle. When I open that page, I don't want to load the full image to be loaded, rather a smaller version that is exactly the window size. Just like in a img-tag i want to set a height/width for that image, and those should be my window size.

Comment: please show some code you've already done.  Also, are you just asking how to make your entire image show and not be cropped by the window?  Try looking into `background-size:contain` or `background-size:cover`.  If it's a loading issue, then you'll need to have different CSS for different breakpoints (media queries)

Comment: To have more chance to be understood and recive quicker reply, try to post the code you have with the question

Comment: Nope, saddly not. I know how to set up a full sized background. But I would like to know if I can crop the size, so that a smaller device will load a smaller image without using different images.

Comment: @ChrisK, you can't crop images with css in the way that images gets smaller in file size. You've to do this server side with PHP or something in combination with CSS media queries as posted in my answer.

Comment: @Roy so I don't have a css solution for that, thanks so far!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is something you can only accomplish by Javascript (I personally prefer jQuery).

Because you only want to load *one* image and **not** load in another image whenever the window gets bigger (as Roy's answer accomplishes).

**The jQuery would be something similar to:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($(window).width() <= 800) { // if the width is equal to, or smaller than 800 px.
        $("body").css("background","url(image-800.jpg) no-repeat"); // load the small image 
    } else { // if the width is bigger than 800 px
        $("body").css("background","url(image-1920.jpg) no-repeat"); // load the bigger image.
    }
});
```

[**JSFiddle demo with your gravatar**](http://jsfiddle.net/whLqzs58/)

Note: To test the demo, your must load the page with a small width, then reload it with a width bigger than 800px.

Comment: Only accomplish with Javascript, I don't think so. Have you tested my answer with your network tab open in Chrome Devtools? Only one image will load regarding your viewport. When you resize to the size for the other image, that one will be loaded. No need for Javascript and pure CSS is much cleaner.

Comment: Exactly, it does load the other image aswell (if the screen gets bigger at a point). But the OP commented in your answer that he wants to load exactly ONE image, so either the big one OR the small one, and not the small one if the bigger one was already loaded before. That's only accomplishable with Javascript.

Comment: @ChrisK, it that true? Please clarify your question. I can't conclude that from your question.

Comment: @Roy His question contains "I don't want to load the 1920 x 1020 resolution, only the 800 x 800".

Comment: @Roy [As your see in your solution](http://jsfiddle.net/2jfqkww9/) (resize the width of the viewport), your solution does load both images.

Answer (score 2):

So you want to load a different image regarding the viewport? Use CSS media queries for that:

```
body {
    background: url(image-1920.png);
}

@media(max-width:800px){
    body {
        background: url(image-800.png); 
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to load exactly one image, and that image should be exact the window size. This may sound dumb because when I load the image in a 800 x 800 resolution and then go to full screen the resolution of the background would be really bad. But thats what I want to achieve for now.

Comment: Changed your answer to add `body {` in the media queries, as otherwise you don't change any css. :)

Answer (score 0):

The css of the body tag mus be 100% (width: 100%) or else you can use **background-size** property to set the size of your image in the background.